# What is the difference between normal, platinum, iridium plugs in petrol/LPG vehicle?

Tags: sparkplugs

This question was related with this  [What is the difference between normal, platinum, iridium plugs?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/2013/what-is-the-difference-between-normal-platinum-iridium-plugs)
Is there any difference if petrol vehicle is converted to liquid propane gas (LPG)? In my case I have Volvo with engine [B5254T](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volvo_Modular_engine#B5254T)

> The B5254T is turbocharged with a low pressure turbo (LPT) producing a maximum of 6 psi (41 kPa).[16] Output is 190 hp (142 kW; 193 PS) at 5100 rpm with 199 lb·ft (270 N·m) of torque at 1800 rpm

Owner manual recommend platinum plugs. But how about when engine operates with LPG? 
[NGK](http://www.ngk.com.au/spark-plugs/technical-information/lpg-compatibility) website says this:

> There are two critical factors that need to be understood when converting a vehicle from petrol to LPG:
>
> - LPG burns hotter
> - LPG increases the voltage requirement at the
>     electrode gap In an attempt to correct these two factors, as a general
>     rule we suggest to:
>
> Use a spark plug that is one heat range colder than standard to
>   compensate for the increased heat from LPG:
>
> The temperature profile of an engine may vary between vehicles. As
>   such, the effect of LPG on the operating temperature of one vehicle
>   may not be the same for another vehicle.

Can I use basic copper plugs and change it at shorter interval? And how about performance? Can it decrease if I am using copper plugs? And if I am using copper plugs, does it hurt to engine?   At this moment I have [NGK LPG LaserLine plugs](http://www.ngk.de/en/sales/products-and-assortments/spark-plugs/lpg-laserline/)

[image: NGK LPG LaserLine]

Or can I just use platinum plugs (OEM or equivalent) if engine is operating with LPG?

Thanks!

Comment: It's probably the same difference you'd see in gasoline/petrol engines, that being longevity. Not for sure though, so leaving this as a comment.

Comment: If i am remember correctly, then NGK LPG 1 must change after 30000 km, but volvo oem plugs is recommended to change at 60000 km interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with this:

> Use a spark plug that is one heat range colder than standard to compensate for the increased heat from LPG

Copper spark plugs won't do any damage if they are not too "hot" (dissipates(transfers heat to cylinder head) heat fast enough).

Volvo OEM Platinum plugs are very good - you can safely use them in LPG setup.